# Query regarding data directories in PE

Tags: executable, portable-executable

I am trying to build a packer for executables and there is one thing on which i didnt understand even after going through the pe doc carefully. To what RVA's do the directories such as (IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT , IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT etc., ) point to?

Answer (score 2):

The official PE documentation, for an unknown reason, doesn't give the name of the structures pointed by the IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY.Rva fields.

Below are the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_XXX (from winnt.h) and their corresponding structures. Those structures are defined in winnt.h except where noted:

```
// Directory Entries

#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT          0   // IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT          1   // IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE        2   // IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION       3   // IMAGE_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY 
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY        4   // WIN_CERTIFICATE (wintrust.h)
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC       5   // IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DEBUG           6   // IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_ARCHITECTURE    7   // IMAGE_ARCHITECTURE_HEADER (Dec and Aplha processors only)
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_GLOBALPTR       8   // RVA of Global pointer (GP) for MIPS
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS             9   // IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY[32|64]
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG    10   // IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY[32|64]
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT   11   // IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT            12   // IMAGE_THUNK_DATA
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT   13   // ImgDelayDescr (delayimp.h)
#define IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR 14   // IMAGE_COR20_HEADER (corhdr.h)
```

Nearly all those structures are discussed in section 2.4.3 (Optional Header Data Directories) in the [official PE documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) (as a side note, at the time I'm writing this, the section are wrongly numbered in the table in chapter 2.4.3 for the documentation version 8.3).